# Add/remove users to/from AAD group in batches

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

What is the code to add users to AAD group or remove users from AAD group in batches in C#? (first find batch size and then add or remove users). Any sample code would be great.

UPDATE:

I added the following code:

```
        private HttpRequestMessage MakeRequest(AzureADUser user, Guid targetGroup)
        {
            return new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Patch, $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{targetGroup}")
            {
                Content = new StringContent(MakeAddRequestBody(user), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"),
            };
        }

        private static string MakeAddRequestBody(AzureADUser user)
        {
            JObject body = new JObject
            {
                ["members@odata.bind"] = JArray.FromObject($"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user.ObjectId}")
            };
            return body.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
        }

        public async Task AddUsersToGroup1(IEnumerable<AzureADUser> users, AzureADGroup targetGroup)
        {           
            try
            {                
                var batches = GetBatchRequest(users, targetGroup.ObjectId);
                foreach (var batchRequestContent in batches)
                {
                    var response = await _graphServiceClient
                        .Batch
                        .Request()
                        .WithMaxRetry(10)
                        .PostAsync(batchRequestContent);
                    var responses = await response.GetResponsesAsync();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
```

On running this I get the following exception: Object serialized to String. JArray instance expected. What am I missing? Also, once I get the responses, I need to check if all of the response returned an 'OK' response or not similar to:

```
return responses.Any(x => x == ResponseCode.Error) ? ResponseCode.Error : ResponseCode.Ok;
```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Add users into AAD Group in batch:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

var additionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        {"members@odata.bind", new List<string>()}
    };
(additionalData["members@odata.bind"] as List<string>).Add("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}"");
(additionalData["members@odata.bind"] as List<string>).Add("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}"");

var group = new Group
{
    AdditionalData = additionalData
};

await graphClient.Groups["{group-id}"]
   .Request()
   .UpdateAsync(group);
```

There is not an endpoint which we can use to remove users from AAD Group in batch. But there is a [batch endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching) which combines multiple requests in one HTTP call. It seems to have a limitation of 20. So we can't delete too many users in one call.

Here is an example, remove users from AAD Group in batch (Reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/batch-requests?tabs=csharp)):

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
var removeUserRequest1 = graphClient.Groups["{group-id}"].Members["{id}"].Reference.Request().GetHttpRequestMessage();
var removeUserRequest2 = graphClient.Groups["{group-id}"].Members["{id}"].Reference.Request().GetHttpRequestMessage();

removeUserRequest1.Method = HttpMethod.Delete;
removeUserRequest2.Method = HttpMethod.Delete;

var batchRequestContent = new BatchRequestContent();

batchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStep(removeUserRequest1);
batchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStep(removeUserRequest2);

await graphClient.Batch.Request().PostAsync(batchRequestContent);
```

Comment: Thank you! Let's say I need too add 500k users. Could I use the same code? Or could you provide the code for the same? Thank you!

Comment: Also, is there a way to first calculate batch size and then add/remove users? Please let me know.

Comment: Could you please check the UPDATED section and answer the same? Thank you!

Comment: @user989988 I don't think you can use this code to add 500k users. Please use csv file to create the users on portal.

Comment: @user989988 But 500K is too large. And as I suggested before, you can't add 500K users into a tenant.

Comment: Could you please answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73922538/batch-request-to-delete-users-from-a-group-does-not-return-user-object-id-when-a?noredirect=1#comment130525522_73922538